# How can I write bindings for the given C structure using dart ffi?

Tags: c, dart, ffi, cinterop

I was trying to write dart ffi bindings for the following C structure but I'm getting errors of all sorts. Can somebody help me with this?

```
 typedef struct {
   enum CXCursorKind kind;
   int xdata;
   const void *data[3];
 } CXCursor;
```

Also for the following code

```
 typedef void *CXIndex;
```

I was using it as `Pointer<Void>` but I want to able to use it as `CXIndex`.

This is for a package that provides bindings to `libclang` in dart. Your suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for the help in advance.